# UV Project Modifier doesn't use alpha correctly?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, uv, texture-painting

I can map textures with alpha (that I paint in the UV Image editor) and make them partially transparent in the BI renderer.

But when I use the UV Project modifier and allocate the loaded alpha image it disregards the transparency but will show the material colour.

In the material panel when I turn on transparency it ignores the texture slot. I guess because there is no available texture in the texture panel?

I have to manually add a regular texture and turn on the alpha with colour. Then back in the modifier turn off override.

It seems odd that it won't correctly apply the alpha as transparent.

Why can't alpha transparency work from the UV Project modifier?

Comment: In cylces there is no issue with transparency. I hardly use BI any more, but it looks like you do have to have an image in the texture associated to your material. Here's a file with two scenes, one for Cycles and One with Internal. Hope this helps. http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29824

Comment: Thank you, yes I guessed as much oh well. I need to use BI for speed of render without a GPU to render on :(